# Adding Labels to UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I'm making my first app and I am having problems with the UIScrollView. I add the scroll view to my storyboard and call my method in viewDidLoad

```
-(void)createScroll{
[scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 900)];
}
```

When I build the application, the scroll view works perfectly and appears to scroll the whole set value of 900. However, when I add a label to the scroll view via the interface builder and run the program it doesn't scroll the whole length. It only will scroll about 500. No matter what I change the value to it still scrolls the same amount. If I delete the label it works like it should. Anybody know what is going on?

Comment: just a hunch but if you are using auto layout move the call to "createScroll" to the viewDidAppear method and see what happens.

Comment: Sure enough. That was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: cool, added it as the answer so that it can help others.

Comment: One other question. I have a button added to the scroll view that pulls up another view, but when I return to the view with the button the scroll view doesn't start from the top, it starts it from the position I left the view on. Therefore I am not able to scroll to the top, but I get 900 of white space below the button. Is there a way to keep the original frame, but have the view load from where it left off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using auto layout move the call to "createScroll" to the viewDidAppear method and see what happens.